# Regex to match specific phrase finished or not with exclamation mark?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match a specific phrase finished or not with exclamation mark.

I made this regex that should match only `Lorem Ipsum` and `Lorem Ipsum!`:

```
/(?:Lorem Ipsum|Lorem Ipsum!)\b/
```

but it doesn't work with `Lorem Ipsum!` (with exclamation mark).

EDIT: It should match only with `Lorem Ipsum` and nothing else or `Lorem Ipsum!` and nothing else, I mean it shouldn't match with `Lorem Ipsum!eeeee`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Not to forget about global flag.

Comment: [**`/Lorem Ipsum!?/`**](https://regex101.com/r/N5cs0F/1) or [**`/Lorem Ipsum(?:!?|\b)/`**](https://regex101.com/r/9vQ5c6/1). (you can add the `g` modifier to match every occurence and the `i` to ignore case).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thanks!! but how can I make it to work with `b/`, because if I have `Lorem Ipsum!eee` it also match and it shouldn't.

Comment: Use `/\bLorem Ipsum\b!?/`

Comment: @MohaMad If the OP genuiinely wants it to be at end of line, there can only be one match anyway, so `/g` doesn't add anything.  Also, a previous comment already suggested the same thing.

Comment: If you really need  a regex to match a *whole string* like the 2 posted, you need `/^Lorem Ipsum!?$/`

Comment: @zizau So you want to match `Lorem Ipsum` in `HelloLorem Ipsum here`? I still think `/\bLorem Ipsum\b!?/` will work better if you want to match this phrase in a longer text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
/Lorem Ipsum!?(?=\s|$)/g
```

it uses a lookahead to check if the character following the last character (`!` or `m`) is either a space `\s` or the end of the line `$`.

**Note 1:** Add the `g` to match all occurences, and the `i` modifier to ignore the case.

[**Regex101 example**](https://regex101.com/r/IraSg1/1).

Comment: Thank you very much! It works and is just what I needed!!

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
/lorem ipsum[!]?/
```

You can find a cheatsheet for regex and test them on: http://www.regexr.com

Comment: The square brackets around the exclamation mark do not contribute anything, and you seem to have dropped the `\b` which was part of the OP's requirements, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
/Lorem Ipsum!?\b/
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason `/prefix|prefix with suffix/` doesn't work is that most regex engines prefer the leftmost match in an alternation.  Simply reordering it should work.

However, as others have suggested, making just the exclamation mark optional is a hugely more readable solution.

```
/Lorem Ipsum!?$/
```

Since you apparently genuinely want to anchor to end of line, you should use `$` at the end rather than `\b`.

Comment: It won't work because `!` is in the set `\b`. This will still match `Lorem Ipsum!eee` even though [OP doesn't want it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777990/regex-to-match-specific-phrase-finished-or-not-with-exclamation-mark?noredirect=1#comment76536729_44777990).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Nice catch! I have updated to make it use $ anyway which works around that nicely.